# Javascript ID not showing reference to input text box - Django

Tags: python, jquery, django, django-views, django-templates

```
    {% extends 'halls/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container">
    <h2>Add Video to {{hall.title}}</h2>
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% load widget_tweaks %}

        {% for field in form %}

        <div class="form-group {% if field.errors %} alert alert-danger {% endif %}">
            {{ field.errors }}
            {{ field.label_tag }}
            {% render_field field class='form-control' %}
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"> Add</button>
    </form>
    <br>
    <h2>OR</h2>
    <form>
        {% for field in search_form %}

        <div class="form-group ">
            {{ field.errors }}
            {{ field.label_tag }}
            {% render_field field class='form-control' %}
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </form>

    <div id="search_results"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var delayTimer;
        $("#id_search_term").keyup(function (){
            clearTimeout(delayTimer);
            $('#search_results').text('Loadingggg');
        });
    </script>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

this is the HTML code. SO basically the whole idea here is when I inspect the search_form, it should give the id of the input box as "id_search_term". But when I inspect the box, it gives as id="id_search".

I am not able to find a way to reference the input box with the ID in the script tag

Comment: where is input box in your code  ? You question is not clear .Please can you elaborate more

Comment: As I am using Django framework, the input box will be rendered inside the {% for field in search_form %} tag. @Swati

Comment: Hey, the error was resolved. The mistake here was that I had named the field in the forms.py as search. Instead, it had to be named as search_term. Now the ajax function works well.